# Sequentially amending row values in a matrix using loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, sequential

I don't really know how to word this question so it's easy to understand, so please bear with me.

I have a 2 column matrix and need to amend the values in column 1 according to another matrix, say `h`.

For example, `h` may look like this: `h <- c(11,10,10,8,12)`
and my data matrix looks like:

```
 [1,]    0    0
 [2,]    0    0
 [3,]    0   26
 [4,]    0   44
 [5,]    0    0
 [6,]    0   65
 [7,]    0    0
 [8,]    0    0
 [9,]    0    0
[10,]    0   28
[11,]    0   25
[12,]    0    0
[13,]    0   81
[14,]    0    0
[15,]    0    0 ...
```

etc...

I need to rename the column of zeros, according to the item number in vector `h`. So I need rows 1:11 to be labelled 1, 12:21 to be labelled 2, 22:31 to be labelled 3 etc., like this:

```
 [1,]    1    0
 [2,]    1    0
 [3,]    1   26
 [4,]    1   44
 [5,]    1    0
 [6,]    1   65
 [7,]    1    0
 [8,]    1    0
 [9,]    1    0
[10,]    1   28
[11,]    1   25
[12,]    2    0
[13,]    2   81
[14,]    2    0
[15,]    2    0 ...
```

My problem is being able to specify which rows in column 1 to change. I can easily create a loop which labels the 1's, `data[1:h[1],1) <- 1` but when it comes to the remaining numbers, I cannot find a way to say to R "choose the next X rows, after the ones we've already changed", "then select the next X rows and change to __".

Sorry if I haven't explained my problem too well!

Comment: Just to mention, my matrix 'data' has length equal to the sum of the h values. So in the example above, my data matrix will have 51 rows.

Comment: Try `rep(seq_along(h), h)`

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rep` to replicate the sequence generated (`seq_along(h)`) by the elements of 'h'.

```
m1[,1] <- rep(seq_along(h), h)
```

According to `?seq`

> ‘seq_along’ and ‘seq_len’ are very
>        fast primitives for two common cases....  ‘seq_along’ and ‘seq_len’ return an integer vector

Comment: i would even make a `rep(seq(h),h)`

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I like `seq_along` as it is a bit more general